# Should the reduced chi-sq of a fit to some points be the same as the reduced chi-sq of a fit through a weighted average of those points?

Tags: chi-squared-test, error, fitting

I have nine data points with three of them taken at x = 2, three taken at x = 4, and three more taken at x = 6.  I came up with a straight-line fit for these points, and found the reduced chi-sq of this fit, taking into account the errors in the measurement of each point.  Now, when I take an average of all the points for a specific x-value weighted by the error, the reduced chi-square of the same line fitted through these points is different.  Should this be the case or have I done something wrong in my calculations?

Comment: Consider a different case, where you have 10,000 data points at each of the three X values. I would expect a different value.